# Multiple messages of the same type in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, masstransit

I'm trying to get my head around Azure Service Bus functionality. I have an application deployed to different environments (dev, test, staging, etc.). From what I have seen you can have only one message type per bus? Does it mean that to support each environment I would need a separate instance of the service bus? I'm using Masstransit and since it requires standard version of the service to run, I would have to pay significant money for each instance every month. Is there any workaround? Is using RabbitMQ instead my only option?

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by `you can have only one message type per bus`.

Comment: Service Bus itself doesn't have these restrictions: you can send different messages to the same queue and have queues from different environments in the same namespace. Whether it's good depends on your scenario. I don't know if Mass Transit allows that.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri what I mean is that I have one and the same class for the message in all environments i.e. NotifyMessage. I thought if I had separate endpoint in the service bus for each environment it would be enough, but apparently this is not how the routing in service bus works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing multiple things here. To be more specific - MassTransit topology and Azure Service Bus service. If you deploy an endpoint for mutiple environments (`test` and `prod` for example) to the same Azure Servie Bus namespace, it will obviously collide as MassTransit will use the same entities required for your endpoint for both `test` and `prod`.

Instead of that, you should use a namespace per environment. I.e. create 2 namespaces (for example `project-test.servicebus.windows.net` and `project-prod.servicebus.windows.net`). This way you can deploy the same MassTransit endpoint that will create identical entities, but they will be segregated by namespace.

To your concern about the cost - on the Standard tier you're paying a monthly fee for the service usage (plus all the message transactions, just to be clear), not number of namespaces you're creating.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation